# TF-Slim like argument scopes in lasagne?

Tags: python, lasagne

Is it possible to create an argument scope in lasagne? E.g. I have a number of layers, whose constructors all should have a parameter `param=5` and would like to set it up in one place:

```
    l1 = lasagne.layers.ConvLayer(x, 64, 3, pad=1, flip_filters=False)
    l2 = lasagne.layers.ConvLayer(l1, 64, 3, pad=1, flip_filters=False)
    l3 = lasagne.layers.ConvLayer(l2, 64, 3, pad=1, flip_filters=False)
```

could be changed to:

```
with lasagne.arg_scope(flip_filters=False, pad=1):
        l1 = lasagne.layers.ConvLayer(x, 64, 3)
        l2 = lasagne.layers.ConvLayer(l1, 64, 3)
        l3 = lasagne.layers.ConvLayer(l2, 64, 3)
```

?

A similar thing is available in [TF-Slim](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/slim/README.md).

Comment: ask in the lasagne users forum.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/lasagne-users